# output file/directory name with sql results sqlcmd

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder full of .sql files and a batch file with the following code:

```
@echo OFF
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME% >output.txt
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd -i "%%G" >>output.txt
pause
```

When I run the batch file it does output the results of each `sql` file into `output.txt` but I'd like to print the file name and directory of each `sql` file with the each files result so I know where everything is coming from in output.txt

What do I need to add in my batch file to do this?

Comment: How about something like `for %%G in (*.sql) do echo "%%G" >>output.txt sqlcmd -i "%%G" >>output.txt`

Comment: Thanks but that just outputs the file names without the query results. I've found a solution now (posted below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution now:

```
@echo OFF
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME% >output.txt

echo .>>output.txt  
echo file1.sql >>output.txt 
sqlcmd -i file2.sql  >>output.txt


echo .>>output.txt
echo file2.sql >>output.txt
sqlcmd -i file2.sql  >>output.txt

 start notepad.exe output.txt
```

And I added the last line so that the output file opens up with the SQL Results of the files.